# Add a calculated band to a R stars object

Tags: r, stars

I use R stars package "read_stars" function to open sentinel bands files yielding the following object (Sentinel):

```
stars object with 3 dimensions and 1 attribute
attribute(s):
                                   *Min. 1st Qu. Median     Mean 3rd Qu. Max.  NA's
T31UCP_20220209T105211_SCL.jp2...     4    1805   2588 2739.591    4237 4968 31185
dimension(s):
     from   to  offset delta                refsys point      values x/y
x    7216 7268   3e+05    10 WGS 84 / UTM zone 31N    NA        NULL [x]
y    4560 4649 5400000   -10 WGS 84 / UTM zone 31N    NA        NULL [y]
band    1   11      NA    NA                    NA    NA SCL,...,B12*
```

I calculate LAI yielding a matrix transformed to a stars object (LAI) with st_as_stars:

```
stars object with 2 dimensions and 1 attribute
attribute(s):
         Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. NA's
A1  0.4669408 1.266426 1.343119 1.315336 1.421111 1.561982 2835
dimension(s):
  from to offset delta refsys point values x/y
x    1 53      0    10     NA    NA   NULL [x]
y    1 90    900   -10     NA    NA   NULL [y]
```

How can I fuse the LAI with sentinel? I tried c.stars yielding error message :
"Error in c.stars(r, r_temp) : \n  don't know how to merge arrays: please specify parameter along\n"
I tried many attempts to copy the Sentinel object dimensions to the LAI object without any result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say that the sentinel object is called `s2` and the other `LAI` you can then split the band dimension over attributes, giving them the same number of dimensions (2). Next, you can assign:

```
s = split(s2)
s$LAI = LAI$A1
```

If you would assign `LAI$A1` directly to `s2`, it would be recycled 11 times.